# Java - Libgdx -TiledMap | get screenX & screenY for every Cell in the Map

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development, tiled, tmxtiledmap

as the title says, i'm trying to get the screen coordinates for each cell in my map. is it even possible?
I'm really frustraited and can't figure it out!
I appreciate your help!
note that my map has a **static** position on the screen.

Another note: i have a custom class Cell that extends Actor. I made it to make my cells clickable and it looks like this:

```
public class Cell extends Actor {
private TiledMapTileLayer.Cell tiledMapCell;
private Texture cellTexture;

public Cell(TiledMapTileLayer.Cell tiledMapCell, Field field){
    this.tiledMapCell = tiledMapCell;
    this.field = field;
    this.cellTexture = tiledMapCell.getTile().getTextureRegion().getTexture();
}

public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getTiledMapCell(){
    return this.tiledMapCell;
}

public Texture getCellTexture(){
    return this.cellTexture;
}

public void setCellTexture(Texture texture){
    this.cellTexture = texture;
    this.tiledMapCell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(new TextureRegion(cellTexture)));
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can process like this :

In your Cell class add a new Variable to get the position of the tile.

```
    private Vector2 pos;
```

Change your constructor.

```
    public Cell(TiledMapTileLayer.Cell tiledMapCell, Field field, Vector2 pos) {
        this.tiledMapCell = tiledMapCell;
        this.field = field;
        this.cellTexture = tiledMapCell.getTile().getTextureRegion().getTexture();
        this.pos = pos;
    }
```

In your main class get the number of tiles in the width of your map, do the same for the height and the size of a tile.

```
    int mapWidth = tiledMapTileLayer.getWidth();
    int mapHeight = tiledMapTileLayer.getHeight();
    int tileSize = tiledMapTileLayer.getTileWidth();
```

now use a loop

```
    // These variables will store the coordinates of each new tile. and will be changed at each loop turn.
    int tempX = 0;
    int tempY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth * mapHeight; i++) {
        pos = new Vector2 (tempX + tileSize / 2, tempY + tileSize / 2);

        // Create a new cell with your Cell class, pass it the position.    
        new Cell(TiledMapTileLayer.Cell tiledMapCell, Field field, pos)

        // Increase the tempX
        tempX += tileSize;
        // If the first line is finish we go to the next one.
        if (tempX > mapWidth * tileSize) {
            tempY += tileSize;
            tempX = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is the method i use cause i did not find any other way.